# Select columns from a table according to result list from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, dynamic

I have two tables as follows.

**--TABLE1 - CONTAINS SOME COLUMN NAMES OF TABLE2**

ID | COL_NAME
1 |    FIRST_NAME
2 |    LAST_NAME
3 |   GENDER

**--TABLE2 - CONTAINS THE ACTUAL VALUES**

ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | AGE | GENDER
10 |   A |              Z|             30  |    M
12 |  B  |             Y |            32   |   F
15 |  C   |            X  |           21   |   M

I want to write a query in SQL SERVER 2005 to fetch records from TABLE2 with only those columns which are exists in TABLE1.

E.g.

I want to select only FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME AND GENDER columns from TABLE2 and should not include AGE as AGE is not there in TABLE1. 
How can I achieve this with or without using a dynamic query?

Comment: @andrewWinn: Perhaps you could reread the question more closely, and see if you really wish that comment to stand.

Comment: As column names must be listed in the body of a SQL statement, how would one dynamically amend the SQL to be run without using dynamic SQL?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens . . . . well played sir . . I missed the meta database design.  <properly chastised and deleted>